# Convert $\| \cdot \|_2 = 0$ to DCP form

Tags: convex-analysis, cvx, cvxpy

I am interested in writing the following equality constraint

$$\|(x+2y, x-y)\|_2 = 0$$

in the [Disciplined Convex Programming](https://dcp.stanford.edu/analyzer?expr=log_sum_exp(log(x)%2C%20log(y))) (DCP) form. I don't know how to convert the operator `==` to satisfy DCP form which presents at above website. I have tested and got that

- `affine_func == affine_func` is satisfied
- `affine_func == contant` is satisfied
- `contant     == affine_func`  is satisfied
- `constant    == constant`   is satisfied

but when i use convex or concave function then the expression can not be satisfied. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The only point that satisfies your constraint is $(0,0)$. Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @Set This's my homework. It requires me to convert an expression to DCP form like i had discribed ablve

Comment: In general, "convex function == constant" is not convex (try x^2 == 4). Here, since the norm is >= 0, your constraint is equivalent to norm <= 0, which is convex.